# Communication between Windows core processes

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi2, iot, windows-iot-core-10

I'm trying to implement a bit of a project, but my problem is, I don't know the specific name of what I'm trying to achieve. I'm in the process of writing a project for a raspberry pi 2, I'd like to have a continually running service (background task) querying the state of a couple of inputs, an adc etc. A second application - a front end gui would be able to query the service whenever it wanted, probably every second or so. What is key to this is that I'd also like the gui to be able to register with the background task for specific events, ie the gui will be running along, polling every second or so, but will also be notified of specific events (input pin changes) that it has registered for. So far, I've looked at wcf and app to app communication but I can't seem to find anything that fits the bill.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I might have asked the question before fully exploring all the solutions. I ended up hosting an AppServiceConnection in a background task. I didn't realise that once the gui had initiated a communication channel with the AppServiceConnection I could keep it open and use it to send messages in the other direction when required.

Thanks.